# editing specific tags of xml to change number type using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml of varying length and i am trying to essentially edit it so for a specific tag  instead of scientific numbers (eg: `<result>0.25e8</result>`) i replace it with its double (eg: `<result>5.43656365692</result>`).

I am trying to use python due to the function `float(x)` as it would be easier.

Any idea how i can just modify these parts of the xml without having to save it, or by just iterating/ reading through it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't insert or delete bytes in the middle of a file without writing at least the whole remains of the file after the modified place. Therefore it would make sense to parse the whole file and either load it in memory or write a modified copy while reading.

Comment: How does `0.25e8` relate to `5.436...`?

Comment: If original and replacement have the same length (or you can afford adjusting values so that it holds true), you could use `mmap` together with e.g. `re.sub` with callable replacement returning `bytes`. How large is your file, so that requirement of in-place modification is critical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML contain text only, but if this is o.k.:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str ="""<root><result>0.25e8</result></root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

for elem in root.iter('result'):
    new_value = 2*float(elem.text)
    elem.text = str(new_value)
    
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<root><result>50000000.0</result></root>
```